# How to handle confirm dialog before toggle button state changed in WPF elegantly?

Tags: wpf, button, dialog, toggle

Say I have a toggle button named `btn1` which show `Open` when state is unchecked and show `Close` when state is checked. I define two functions to simply handle it's checked/unchecked event:

```
private void Btn_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Do some open operation.
}
```

and

```
private void Btn_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Do some close operation.
}
```

Now I want to show a confirm dialog when user click the toggle button. So I add a MessageBox before `do some open/close operation`. The code became to

```
private void Btn_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to open it?", "app name", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
  if(res == MessageBoxResult.OK)
  {
    // Do some open operation.
  }
  else
  {
    btn1.IsChecked = false;
  }
}
```

The unchecked handler is similar as checked handler.

But after I run these code, If I choose to cancel the dialog, then the `checked`/`unchecked` dialog will alternative popup constantly.

So how can I handle this case elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Yahey! I found a solution, but may not elegant.

```
private void Btn_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if(btn1.Tag != null)
  {
    btn1.Tag = null;
    return;
  }

  MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to open it?", "app name", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
  if(res == MessageBoxResult.OK)
  {
    // Do some open operation.
  }
  else
  {
    btn1.Tag = "ignore";
    btn1.IsChecked = false;
  }
}

private void Btn_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if(btn1.Tag != null)
  {
    btn1.Tag = null;
    return;
  }

  MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close it?", "app name", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
  if(res == MessageBoxResult.OK)
  {
    // Do some close operation.
  }
  else
  {
    btn1.Tag = "ignore";
    btn1.IsChecked = true;
  }
}
```